# is there way to create a text file to edit user name and password using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i wanted to create script using python selenium, so when ever i open text file and edit details there then the script should work according to it but its not working.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/deepak/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe")
with open('account details.txt', 'r') as file:
   for details in file:
        "Username, Password, Trainer Battle ID  = details.split(':')"
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/login.php")
# identify username, password and signin elements
driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("Username")
driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys("Password")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/battle_trainer.php")
# identify Enter Trainer Name/Number
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys("Trainer Battle ID")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
```

i have posted a text file image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJU8L.jpg

Comment: ```for details in file:
        "Username, Password, Trainer Battle ID  = details.split(':')"```
is not setting anything

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove quotes from line `"Username, Password, Trainer Battle ID  = details.split(':')"` and make it like `Username, Password, Trainer_Battle_ID  = details.split(':')`. And then replace lines,

```
driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("Username")
driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys("Password")
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys("Trainer Battle ID")
```

with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys(Username)
driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys(Password)
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys(Trainer_Battle_ID)
```

Also, you are reading the text file incorrectly. First you need to split data on the basis of "\n". Then you should split each element of that list using ":". This is the way you can implement this:

```
Username = ""
Password = ""
Trainer_Battle_ID = ""

with open('account_details.txt', 'r') as file:
    details = file.read().split('\n')
    for i in range(0, len(details)):
        details[i] = details[i].split(':')
    Username = details[0][1]
    Password = details[1][1]
    Trainer_Battle_ID = details[2][1]
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/login.php")
# identify username, password and signin elements
driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys(Username)
driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys(Password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/battle_trainer.php")
# identify Enter Trainer Name/Number
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys(Trainer_Battle_ID)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
```